# Postgresql - How to truncate table and insert rows in same table within a single transaction

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I want to truncate a table in PostgreSQL 13 and then insert rows to the same table within a single transaction, so that when I execute the SQL command it will TRUNCATE the table and if during INSERTS anything fails truncated data should be rollback.

Below is the command which I want in a single transaction.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE public.truninsdemo;

INSERT INTO public.truninsdemo (id, name)
VALUES (1, 'Scott'), (2, 'John');
```

UPDATE

I don't want to execute TRUNCATE and INSERT statements as 2 separate commands, separated by a semicolon. I want to achieve results using a single command may be CTE, but not sure how.

Comment: To truncate table and insert rows in same table within a single transaction, you simply have ... to truncate table and insert rows in same table within a single transaction.

Comment: Hello @Atmo Can you please provide a working example for the same. So I can understand it better. Thanks!

Comment: BEGIN; TRUNCATE .... ; INSERT INTO ... ;  COMMIT; That's it. The only thing missing in your example is BEGIN; to start the transaction and COMMIT; to end the transaction.

Comment: So I think my question was not clear, I don't want to execute TRUNCATE and INSERT statements as 2 separate commands, separated by a semicolon. I want to achieve results using a single command may be CTE, but not sure how.

Comment: 1) Why? 2) No per [Select](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH): *Each subquery can be a SELECT, TABLE, VALUES, INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement*. 3) Do as already suggested and use `Begin <statements> Commit`.

Comment: I have to execute this 2 commands in single query because tool (Snaplogic) which I use to execute Sql command it can execute only 1 command at a time. So internally Truncate will be 1 batch/transaction and later Insert in 2nd batch/transaction. So if anything goes wrong during Insert I won't be able to rollback truncate command and old data will be gone.